# Sending OpenShift ETCD data/logs to stdout?

Tags: openshift, etcd

I am trying to figure how to send all data/logs from OpenShift ETCD to stdout so I can see real life data/logs. I know there are graphs we can see in OpenShift Prometheus but I want to see the actual data. Once, the data is sent to stdout it will be sent to Splunk automictically. I cannot figure out the best route...I thought about deploying an image with a script including a while loop to send the data/logs to stdout every 60 seconds. There is not etcdctl command that exports or sends the data. Anyone have any ideas or has completed this before?

Answer (score 0):

To start

```
oc project <etcd project>

# etcd=true is a label.
oc get pods -l etcd=true | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs -I PODNAME oc exec PODNAME -- bash -c 'curl https://localhost:<port you set>/metrics -k --cert <path to secret.crt> --key <path to secret .key>'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a dedicated project called SCK (Splunk Connect for Kubernetes) https://github.com/splunk/splunk-connect-for-kubernetes/releases

For the logging part, it will deploy a daemonset on all of your nodes and fluentd will monitor path `/var/log/containers/*.log` on the physical nodes where logs from containers are written to. Then events are sent to Splunk using HEC (http event collector)

Particular to the etcd usecase, note that chart splunk-kubernetes-logging contains configurations for proper time formatting for etcd container logs:

```
    etcd:
      from:
        pod: etcd-server
        container: etcd-container
      timestampExtraction:
        regexp: (?<time>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} [0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d\.\d{6})
        format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%N"
    etcd-minikube:
      from:
        pod: etcd-minikube
        container: etcd
      timestampExtraction:
        regexp: (?<time>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} [0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d\.\d{6})
        format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%N"
    etcd-events:
      from:
        pod: etcd-server-events
        container: etcd-container
      timestampExtraction:
        regexp: (?<time>\d{4}-[0-1]\d-[0-3]\d [0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d\.\d{6})
        format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%N"
```